# Filling form input field with AutoIT

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, automation, autoit

Trying to automate filling in the input field for amazon seller central with AutoIT.  Everything works great, but maybe the page loads to slow or something but the string I'm sending to the form input element is getting truncated. Here's my code:

```
#include <IE.au3>



$oIE = _IECreate()
_IENavigate($oIE, "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/home")
Local $oAddress = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
ConsoleWrite($oAddress & @CRLF)
$oSignin = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sign-in/sign-in.html?destination=https%3A%2F%2Fsellercentral.amazon.com%2Fhz%2Fhome"
if $oAddress = $oSignin Then
ConsoleWrite("Sucess! Connected!" & @CRLF)
Else
    ConsoleWrite("You are not on the sign in page")
EndIf
_IELoadWait($oIE)
Local $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "signinWidget")
Local $oInputFile = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "username")

; Assign input focus to the field and then send the text string
_IEAction($oInputFile, "focus")

; Select exisiting content so it will be overwritten

_IEAction($oInputFile, "selectall")


Send("12345678@asdfasdfdasfasd.com")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the send function because it is not very reliable. Try _IEFormElementSetValue instead. Most of the IE functions have a built in load wait function so they won't execute the next line of code until the web page is loaded.

This code works for me:

```
#include <IE.au3>

;change this to your login info
login("12345@gmail.com", "FakePass")

Func login($sUserName, $UserPass)
    Local $oIE, $sSignin, $sAddress, $oForm, $oUserInput, $oUserPassInput

    $oIE = _IECreate("https://sellercentral.amazon.com/hz/home")

    $sAddress = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
    ConsoleWrite($sAddress & @CRLF)

    $sSignin = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/sign-in/sign-in.html?destination=https%3A%2F%2Fsellercentral.amazon.com%2Fhz%2Fhome"
    If $sAddress = $sSignin Then
        ConsoleWrite("Sucess! On sign in page!" & @CRLF)
    Else
        ConsoleWrite("You are not on the sign in page" & @CRLF)
        Return
    EndIf

    $oForm = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "signinWidget")
    $oUserInput = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "username")
    $oUserPassInput = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($oForm, "password")

    ;set user name
    _IEFormElementSetValue($oUserInput, $sUserName)

    ;set pass
    _IEFormElementSetValue($oUserPassInput, $UserPass)

    _IEFormSubmit($oForm)
EndFunc   ;==>login
```